# Slick JS Slider Not Working

Tags: jquery, carousel, slick.js

I've been combing all the articles for this issue and I can't find a solution.

I'm not getting anything working. Here's the code:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Slick</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bower_components/slick-carousel/slick/slick.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bower_components/slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css" />

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

    <style>
        body {
            background: #333; 
            margin: 0; 
        }
        div {
            outline: none;
        }
        #container {
            width: 600px;
            height: 250px; 
            background: transparent url(media/bg-headline.jpg) no-repeat center center; 
            position: relative;

        }
        #cta {
            position: absolute;
            right: 0; 
            bottom:0; 
            padding: 10px; 
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div class="center">
            <div><h1>1</h1><div>
            <div><h1>2</h1><div>
            <div><h1>3</h1><div>
        </div>
        <div id="cta"><a href="#"><img src="media/12254-cta.png" alt="Learn More >" width="100"></a></div>
    </div>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/slick-carousel/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="js/12254.js"></script>-->






    <script>document.write('<script src="http://' + (location.host || 'localhost').split(':')[0] + ':35729/livereload.js?snipver=1"></' + 'script>')</script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
// Slick Version: Center Mode
$('.center').slick({
  centerMode: true,
  centerPadding: '60px',
  slidesToShow: 3,
  responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 768,
      settings: {
        arrows: false,
        centerMode: true,
        centerPadding: '40px',
        slidesToShow: 3
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 480,
      settings: {
        arrows: false,
        centerMode: true,
        centerPadding: '40px',
        slidesToShow: 1
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

The numbers show up in a vertical line. There is no carousel at all. I've tried several versions of the links to `slick.js`, `slick.min.js` and even different versions of jQuery but to no avail.

What am I overlooking?

Comment: 1) Are you getting any errors in the console, 2) is your JS included inside a `document.ready` block and after everything else?

Comment: No errors. But I think I found the issue. There were some `<div>`s that weren't closed (DUH! STOOPID). I tried with `.single-item` and it works but the Center Mode isn't working yet.

Comment: OK, I got it to somewhat work. The images are all stacked next to each other, so there's a spacing issue. And the pre/next arrows don't work properly. But at least I'm getting somewhere!

Comment: Hehe nice. If you make a fiddle or codepen it'll be easier to help troubleshoot any issues